# UIImagePickerController hides some views and corrupts view hierarchy

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout, uicollectionview, uiimagepickercontroller

I have vertically positioned 6 buttons that the last one stands at the very bottom of the page. There is one dynamically added collection view between 5th and 6th buttons. Whenever I add collection view between them, I update 6th one's position (sliding it down) and it goes out of bounds so I am updating scroll view's contentSize accordingly, so good so far.

I am using `UIImagePickerController` which is being showed when one of those buttons is tapped. Here is the problem. If I either pick an image or cancel picking, my dynamically created collection view getting hidden and the 6th button I updated position earlier goes back to its original position (even though all variables/sources that related with my collection view have the correct values, so I assume that the page is not reloaded).

Since picking an image or canceling the `UIImagePickerController` has absolutely nothing to do with my any view's position/visibility (including collection view), I wonder why collection view gets hidden.

Here is how I show `UIImagePickerController`:

```
self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
self.imagePicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
self.presentViewController(self.imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Here is how I add collection view dynamically:

```
let frameForCollectionView = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)

self.addChildViewController(self.collectionViewController)
self.collectionViewController.view.frame = frameForCollectionView
self.containerView.addSubview(collectionViewController.view)
self.collectionViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

Here is where I handle when picking canceled or an image picked:

```
 func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
            // Setting picked image to the button's image here.
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        }

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
```

To see what's going on at the background, I check the design on `Debug View Hierarchy` right after the collection view gets hidden and I don't see the collection view there.

You may need to know these: I am using auto layout, testing on simulator (iPhone 4S, iOS 9.3).

Is there anyone who has any idea why dynamically added collection view gets hidden and how to prevent that behaviour?

**EDIT:**

I updated dismiss code as the following:

```
self.imagePicker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

**EDIT 2:**

I updated presentation style as well:

```
self.imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.OverCurrentContext
```

So the problem is half solved. I have the same problem only after picking and cropping image (i.e. not canceling). That's probably because of the view we crop images is another view than photos view, so I may need to set cropping page presentation style or any other solution. **Any ideas?**

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what's going on, but I noticed you're calling self.dismiss....  dont you mean to dismiss the picker instead? `picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)`

Comment: Sorry for that, I updated but no luck.